# unable to deploy rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

my rails app works in development mode on my mac. Whrn i try to compile into heroku i get errors on the command line

```
    Cleaning up the bundler cache.
           Removing bundler (1.3.2)
    -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
    -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
           Running: rake assets:precompile
           rake aborted!
           undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
           /tmp/build_9afd2a8f-0be9-427c-82f9-5431cf3a30fc/config/initializers/devise.rb:234:in `block in <top (required)>'
           /tmp/build_9afd2a8f-0be9-427c-82f9-5431cf3a30fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.1.2/lib/devise.rb:276:in `setup'
           /
           /tmp/build_9afd2a8f-0be9-427c-82f9-5431cf3a30fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `bl
     /tmp/build_9afd2a8f-0be9-427c-82f9-5431cf3a30fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_9afd2a8f-0be9-427c-82f9-5431cf3a30fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_9afd2a8f-0be9-427c-82f9-5431cf3a30fc/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_9afd2a8f-0be9-427c-82f9-5431cf3a30fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
       /tmp/build_9afd2a8f-0be9-427c-82f9-5431cf3a30fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

checked my devise.rb
the only line i added was

```
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['facebook_api_key'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['facebook_api_secret'], scope: "email, publish_actions"

and this is my gemfile - as you can see i have the production and development information included


group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

as advised devise 230-238

```
# ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
   config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['facebook_api_key'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['facebook_api_secret'], scope: "email, publish_actions"

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not supported by Devise, or
  # change the failure app, you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
```

Comment: How `FACEBOOK_CONFIG` constant is initialised?

Comment: gem 'omniauth-facebook'

Comment: paste your config/initializers/devise.rb: line number 230-238

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to stop using this magick `FACEBOOK_CONFIG` variable and start using environment variables for heroku

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_API_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_API_SECRET'], scope: "email, publish_actions"
```

to get this ENV working on development easier please check: 
https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv
or 
https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `FACEBOOK_CONFIG` that you're trying to use is `nil`.

First you have to set the two [environment variables in your Heroku account](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars):

```
$ heroku config:set FACEBOOK_API_KEY=your-key-here
$ heroku config:set FACEBOOK_API_SECRET=your-secret-here
```

Then verify these are set correctly:

```
$ heroku config:get FACEBOOK_API_KEY
$ heroku config:get FACEBOOK_API_SECRET
```

Finally update the `device.rb` file as follows:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_API_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_API_SECRET'], scope: "email, publish_actions"
```

Now should be good to go.

Comment: nope! still get running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
       /tmp/build_62d4393a-c482-40d0-958d-d56613ff2745/config/initializers/devise.rb:234:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_62d4393a-c482-40d0-958d-d56613ff2745/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.1.2/lib/devise.rb:276:in `setup'
       /tmp/build_62d4393a-c482-40d0-958d-d56613ff2745/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: Have you commited the changes and pushed to Heroku?

Comment: It seems like something is cached. Can you post your complete `devise.rb` file? Also can you remove the `tmp/` folder from the remote repo?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with Devise.
the error says

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

If you look at the next line down it is coming from.

```
config/initializers/devise.rb:234
```

So the error is on line 234 in config/initializers/devise.rb.

Run the following command on your mac.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

If you don't get the same error, then you know that it is an issue with your production environment.

Can you add what you have on line config/initializers/devise.rb:234

Comment: config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['facebook_api_key'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['facebook_api_secret'], scope: "email, publish_actions"

Answer (score 0):

Just update your facebook.yml file with same information for production. I guess you only have development.

/config/facebook.yml

```
development:
  facebook_api_key: copy_from_here
  facebook_api_secret: copy_2_from_here

production:
  facebook_api_key: paste_to_here
  facebook_api_secret: paste_2_here
```